# How to fix this seam?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I'm fairly new to Blender, this time it's giving me a strange seam running at weird angles to the mesh and I don't know where I went wrong or how to solve it

I also tried UV unwrapping it along all the relevant seems and that did not change anything, so I removed my original Unwrap and still it happens, even when the Texture Coordinate set to Object

Blend File:
https://pasteall.org/blend/0e0b55e3ca254b3d9c82037255315484

[image]

[image]

Comment: You didn't pack the image called FabricDenim003_DISP_3K.jpg, so we can't see anything, plus you need to create a Displacement node between the Image Texture node and the Output node, as pointed out by Hiserod

Comment: Ahh true, sorry about that, but it was happening with all textures I tried to plug into it, and Hiserod did solve this for me, thank you for helping also! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gray sockets are for scalar (single e.g. 0.73 or 512.256) values, and blue sockets are for 3D vector values such as <0.0, 0.707, 0.707> or <5.1, 8.2, 3.3> (one for each axis).

Since Blender supports vector displacement, the Displacement socket is now a vector socket. When you link a scalar to a vector socket, the three vector components all receive the same value. For example, 0.618 would become <0.618, 0.618, 0.618> and -1 <-1, -1, -1>. This conversion from a scalar to a vector can only result in two directions along one axis, but normals can face in any direction. For example, a sphere's normals face away from the center in every direction.

The Displacement node can convert a scalar to a vector that can be used for displacement/bump by making use of the object's existing normals. It should give you the results that you're looking for.

Press <kbd>**Shft**</kbd><kbd>**A**</kbd>, Vector (<kbd>**V**</kbd>), Displacement (<kbd>**D**</kbd>) to add one.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Omg thank you so much! That was 100% the problem, I can't believe i forgot about displacement nodes, I've even used them in a tutorial in the past and completely skipped it

Also thank you for the tips about which colors go into what, that helps a lot too! 

I have accepted this answer, thanks again!